# How to do polymorphic associations in Doctrine 1.2?

Tags: symfony-1.4, polymorphic-associations, doctrine-1.2

Is it possible to do polymorphic associations with doctrine 1.2 (!) in symfony 1.4?

I have, for example, the following in my schema.yml:

```
alBillingElement:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:

  columns:
     id: {type: integer(11), primary: true, autoincrement: true}
     object_type: {type: varchar(20)}
     object_id: {type: integer(11)}
     task: {type: varchar(20)}
     parameter: {type: text}
     amount: {type: float}
```

`object_type` contains the model name of the object referenced by `object_id`.
Can I somehow define a relationship so that i can query the "object" using relations?

Comment: As i know Doctrine 1.2.4 dosen't use polymorphic associations but otherwise you can use native sql.

Comment: sadly i think you are true. But how can i use both my models and raw sql? if i work with docrines #addComponent method it conplains it cannot find the association, which i cannot define :/